# Remove values from an array of int

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I've written this small C function to remove integers from an array.

```
/* remove `count` integers from `arr`, starting at index `idx` */
void remove_int(int (*arr)[100], int idx, int count)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (j = idx; *arr[j]; j++)
            *arr[j] = *arr[j+1];
}
```

Say I run it like this:

```
int arr[100] = {25, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2};

remove_int(&arr, 7, 2);
```

I get a Segmentation Fault. Why?

**EDIT** [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413397/remove-values-from-an-array-of-int#comment70030755_41413397) by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) solved it, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419267/7292857) by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) explained it. Thanks guys!

Comment: `*arr[j]` --> `(*arr)[j]`

Comment: Your function doesn't use `idx`?

Comment: BTW `remove_int(&arr, 7, 2);` --> `remove_int(&arr, 2, 7);` ?

Comment: Also your array has 7 integers, indexing from `0-6`, but you use `7` when calling `remove_int()`. Additionally, why not `int arr[] = {25, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2};` instead?

Comment: @Barmar it prevents the function being called with an array of the wrong size

Comment: Is this function supposed to remove the data starting at `idx`? So if you call `remove_int(&arr, 2, 7);`, then the resultant array would decay to `25 4`?

Comment: @RoadRunner  `*arr[j]` is looking for a 0 - supposedly.  `int arr[] = {25, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2};` lacks a 0.

Comment: @chux Yeah that would makes sense. Nevertheless, OP probably needs to clarify this.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not do what you think it does:

- `arr` is defined as a pointer to an array of 100 `int` elements.
- `arr[j]` does not point to the element at offset `j`, but rather to the `j`th array in the array pointed to by `arr`.
- `*arr[j]` dereferences the integer at location `arr[j][0]`, much beyond the end of the `arr` array from the calling function.

If you keep the same API, you should write the code this way:

```
/* remove `count` integers from `arr`, starting at index `idx` */
void remove_int(int (*arr)[100], int idx, int count) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = idx + count; i < 100 && (*arr)[i]; i++)
        (*arr)[i - count] = (*arr)[i];
    for (j = 0; j < count && i - count + j < 100; j++) {
        (*arr)[i - count + j] = 0;
}
```

It is not idiomatic in C to handle pointers to arrays, it is more common to just pass arrays directly, and the called function receives a pointer to the first element of the array.

The function would then be called this way:

```
int arr[100] = {25, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2};

remove_int(arr, 7, 2);
```

And the function would be written this way:

```
/* remove `count` integers from `arr`, starting at index `idx` */
void remove_int(int arr[100], int idx, int count) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = idx + count; i < 100 && arr[i]; i++)
        arr[i - count] = arr[i];
    for (j = 0; j < count && i - count + j < 100; j++) {
        arr[i - count + j] = 0;
}
```

In this case, the `[100]` array size is ignored and the function behaves exactly the same as if it was defined as `void remove_int(int *arr, int idx, int count)`